# Comparing now to saved date/time not working

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime, compare

I have a function that gets my relative DateTime and outputs it in a `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.UUUUU` format.

```
function mb_datetime( $mb_input_time = null, $mb_timezone = null ) {

    $mb_timezone_local      = get_option('timezone_string');
    $mb_timezone_new        = ( empty($mb_timezone) ? $mb_timezone_local : $mb_timezone );
    $mb_timezone_format = ( $mb_timezone == 'UTC' ? 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z' : 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u' );

    $mb_datetime_get        = new DateTime($mb_input_time, new DateTimeZone($mb_timezone_local));
    $mb_datetime_get->setTimeZone( new DateTimeZone($mb_timezone_new) );
    $mb_datetime_get        = $mb_datetime_get->format($mb_timezone_format);

    return $mb_datetime_get;
}
```

I also then have my function that I am trying to use the above function to see whether I need to generate a new access token, or use the saved one because it hasn't lapsed yet:

```
function mb_microsoft_opengraph() {
    if( strtotime(get_option('mb_msgraph_token_expire')) < strtotime(mb_datetime('now')) ) {

        // do if mb_msgraph_token_expire date/time has passed

    }
}
```

I have also tried the if statement without the `strtotime` but I know it should work.

My time formats as of posting are:

```
mb_msgraph_token_expire = 2019-05-10T16:17:57.880819
now                     = 2019-05-14T11:40:10.611465
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?